# Python dictioany syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, dictionary

I am trying to declare a `dictionay` like following

```
dict = { 'key1': "A"= "value" , 'B' = "Valueb" , 
         'key2': "A"= "valueA" , 'B' = "ValueC" ,
}
```

I am getting a syntax error. Can anybody help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `=`s? Are you trying to make a dictionary of dictionaries?

Answer (score 5):

First - don't use dict as a variable name, the correct syntax is below

```
dVals = { 'key1': {"A": "value" , 'B':  "Valueb"} , 
         'key2': {"A": "valueA" , 'B': "ValueC"}}
```

You can find [more on python dictionary syntax in tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

in python a dict key refers to only a dict value..
but in your statement:
     'key1': "A"= "value" , 'B' = "Valueb" 
key1 refers to A and B,it doesn't work !

you should try this :

```
'key1': {"A": "value" , 'B' : "Valueb" }
```

and i suggest you to read the tutorial docs of python .